# SQL 2014 adds null transaction log entries every time a custom service wakes up to look at the database.

Tags: database, database-administration

SQL2014 on Server2012 (12.0.2000)  versus SQL2008R2 (10.50.6000) on Server 2008R2.

In SQL2014 but not in SQL2008 .... Both examples add the noted entries to the transaction log once a second (every time the service wakes up).

This quickly fills up the transaction log.  How do I convince SQL to not log empty transactions?

FogBugz Maintenance Service:

000082f9:00000568:0001    LOP_BEGIN_XACT    UPDATE    0000:0498cabf    0x010500000000000515000000A6B3A121AD55DD462E7FAA2AF3030000    56    2015/06/13 22:42:31:567
000082f9:00000568:0002    LOP_MODIFY_ROW    NULL    0000:0498cabf    NULL    NULL    NULL
000082f9:00000568:0003    LOP_MODIFY_ROW    NULL    0000:0498cabf    NULL    NULL    NULL
000082f9:00000568:0004    LOP_MODIFY_ROW    NULL    0000:0498cabf    NULL    NULL    NULL
000082f9:00000568:0005    LOP_COMMIT_XACT    NULL    0000:0498cabf    NULL    NULL    NULL
000082f9:00000570:0001    LOP_EXPUNGE_ROWS    NULL    0000:00000000    NULL    NULL    NULL
000082f9:00000570:0002    LOP_SET_BITS    NULL    0000:00000000    NULL    NULL    NULL

One of our products

000021f7:00000d50:0001    LOP_BEGIN_XACT    user_transaction    0000:00506a92    0x85AE4624DA408945A9909BDE552F679F    57    2015/06/17 06:39:13:667
000021f7:00000d50:0002    LOP_MODIFY_ROW    NULL    0000:00506a92    NULL    NULL    NULL
000021f7:00000d50:0003    LOP_COMMIT_XACT    NULL    0000:00506a92    NULL    NULL    NULL

Answer (score 0):

Daily backups with truncate were already in place,

Apparently my solution is to make the log file significantly larger in hopes that I won’t have to schedule multiple truncates during the day.